# Are Socket AM2/AM2+ Heatsinks Compatible with Socket AM3 processor?

Tags: heatsink, cpu-cooler, am3

I bought an [Asus Lion Square](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/728/1/) compatible with a [AMD Athlon II X3 435](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103724) Socket AM3 processor?

I know strictly speaking, the Lion Square specifies AM2 but I'm a little confused since AM2 and AM3 are suppose to be socket compatible (I'm a little confused here as well but I assume it means an AM3 board will support AM2/AM2+ CPUs).

However, will there be a problem with chip height and spacing? Or do people have experience asking ASUS for a standoff adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else was wondering about this problem, it seems to work.

My guess is that the AM2/AM3 sockets are comparable since AMD, especially for heatsinks. Theres just a bar mount that goes across the socket.

Anyways, it worked for my situiation.

Comment: comparable or compatible?